# php autoload: duplication of db connection

Tags: php, oop, pdo, autoload

Why does this `autoload` class duplicate the db connection?

```
class autoloader
{
    private $directory_name;

    public function __construct($directory_name)
    {
        $this->directory_name = $directory_name;
    }

    public function autoload($class_name) 
    { 
        $file_name = 'class_'.strtolower($class_name).'.php';

        $file = AP_SITE.$this->directory_name.'/'.$file_name;

        if (file_exists($file) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        include ($file);
    }
}

# nullify any existing autoloads
spl_autoload_register(null, false);

# specify extensions that may be loaded
spl_autoload_extensions('.php, .class.php, .lib.php');

# instantiate the autoloader object
$classes_2 = new autoloader('classes');

# register the loader functions
spl_autoload_register(array($classes_2, 'autoload'));

$connection = new database_pdo(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
var_dump($connection);
```

result,

```
object(database_pdo)[2]
  protected 'connection' => 
    object(PDO)[3]
```

The db connection class is located in a folder called 'classes',

```
class database_pdo
{
    # database handler
    protected $connection = null;

    # make a connection
    public function __construct($dsn,$username,$password)
    {
        try 
        {
            # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
            $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            # call the get_error function
            $this->get_error($e);
        }
    }

    ...

    # closes the database connection when object is destroyed
    public function __destruct()
    {
        # set the handler to NULL closes the connection propperly
        $this->connection = null;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this mistake?

**EDIT:**

the result it should be,

```
object(database_pdo)[1]
      protected 'connection' => 
        object(PDO)[2]
```

I only get above as the result if I don't use the `autoloader` class, so I think there must be something I have done wrong in the code of `autoloader` class.

But I don't know which line is wrong...

**EDIT:**

If I use `print_r`,

```
print_r($connection);
```

Result,

```
Object ( [connection:protected] => PDO Object ( ) )
```

**EDIT:**

I get even more 'duplicates' if I use this [autoload](http://php-autoloader.malkusch.de/en/) class by someone else,

> object(database_pdo)[11]   protected 'connection' => 
>       object(PDO)[13]

**EDIT:**

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    include AP_SITE."classes_1/class_".$class_name.".php";
}

$connection = new database_pdo(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
var_dump($connection);
```

result,

```
object(database_pdo)[1]
  protected 'connection' => 
    object(PDO)[2]
```

but I will get error if I want to load classes from other directories,

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    include AP_SITE."classes_1/class_".$class_name.".php";
    include AP_SITE."classes_2/class_".$class_name.".php";
}
```

message,

> Warning:
>   include(C:/wamp/www/art_on_your_doorstep_2011_MVC/global/applications/CART/classes_2/class_database_pdo.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in ...

which refers to this line - `include AP_SITE."classes_2/class_".$class_name.".php";`

**EDIT:**

This one is working like I expect,

```
function system_autoload($class) {
   // $class = str_replace('_', '/', strtolower($class.'.php'));
    if(file_exists(AP_SITE.'classes_1/class_'.$class.'.php')) {
        include_once(AP_SITE.'classes_1/class_'.$class.'.php');

    } else if(file_exists(AP_SITE.'classes_2/class_'.$class.'.php')) {
        include_once(AP_SITE.'classes_2/class_'.$class.'.php');
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('system_autoload');
```

But it is not generic at all as I have duplicate the code inside when I have more than 2 directories.

Comment: autoload =/= new. With autoload you can create one, two or even one hundred connection objects. So it's not the autoload function that is duplicating the connection object, it's your code.

Comment: Sorry, where's the duplicate?

Comment: @lauthiamkok What version of PHP are you using? My `var_dump()` results don't look like that. I get a format like `object(class)#id (propertyCount)`. I think you may be misinterpreting the results of `var_dump()`.

Comment: @Phil my PHP version is 5.3.4. My `var_dump()` will return the result like this - `object(class)#id (propertyCount)` when I run it on 5.2.x.

Comment: Or maybe it is the `database_pdo class` that I have done wrong?

Comment: @lauthiamkok Mine is 5.3.5 but XDebug might be messing with the results. Try `print_r` instead.

Comment: @Phil I get nothing with `print_r`. please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok Doesn't look like nothing. Looks correct to me.

Comment: @Phil thanks. So it is not duplicating? What are those numbers mean? See my edit above thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say those numbers are object IDs. These are sequential numbers assigned to PHP objects as they are instantiated.

In your code, object #1 is your autoloader, #2 is your `database_pdo` class and #3 is `PDO`.

Comment: @lauthiamkok This is now an entirely different question. Your original autloader looked more capable of handling this new problem

Comment: true! I am going to search other other better solutions... thanks!

Comment: got a solution but it is not generic enough...please see my edit above. thanks.