# How can I load classes from multiple directories with __autoload?

Tags: php, oop, pdo, autoload

Following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711450/php-autoload-duplication-of-db-connection), it seems that the duplicate issue could be solved by just using the `__autoload` code below,

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    include AP_SITE."classes_1/class_".$class_name.".php";
}

$connection = new database_pdo(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
var_dump($connection);
```

result,

```
object(database_pdo)[1]
  protected 'connection' => 
    object(PDO)[2]
```

but this only loads the classes from one directory, what about other directories? Because I group the classes in different directories. So I will get error if I want to load classes from other directories,

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    include AP_SITE."classes_1/class_".$class_name.".php";
    include AP_SITE."classes_2/class_".$class_name.".php";
}
```

message,

> Warning:
>   include(C:/wamp/www/art_on_your_doorstep_2011_MVC/global/applications/CART/classes_2/class_database_pdo.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in ...

which refers to this line - `include AP_SITE."classes_2/class_".$class_name.".php";`

So, my question is - how can I load classes from multiple directories with `__autoload`?

**a possible solution:**

```
function autoload_class_multiple_directory($class_name) 
{

    # List all the class directories in the array.
    $array_paths = array(
        'classes_1/', 
        'classes_2/'
    );

    # Count the total item in the array.
    $total_paths = count($array_paths);

    # Set the class file name.
    $file_name = 'class_'.strtolower($class_name).'.php';

    # Loop the array.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total_paths; $i++) 
    {
        if(file_exists(AP_SITE.$array_paths[$i].$file_name)) 
        {
            include_once AP_SITE.$array_paths[$i].$file_name;
        } 
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_class_multiple_directory');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can register multiple autoload functions by using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) instead of the single `__autoload` function. That's the recommended way.

If one autoloader was able to load the file, the next one in the stack won't be called.

Each autoloader however should only load the classes it is for, so you need to check that by the classname and/or with `is_file`. By classname often is better because trying wildly on the file-system can stress a system if your application grows.

To not re-invent the wheel, you could even use an autoloader that already exists which is able to deal with the PSR-0 standard on file-name-calling. Those often allow to register a specific namespace on a base-directory. In your case that would mean that you must rename and organize your files according to the [PSR-0 convention](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

---

The quick solution (bound to your question):

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    $file = sprintf('%sclasses_1/class_%s.php', AP_SITE, $class_name);
    if (is_file($file))
    {
        include $file;
        return;
    }
    $file = sprintf('%sclasses_2/class_%s.php', AP_SITE, $class_name);
    if (is_file($file))
    {
        include $file;
        return;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is already code duplicated (as in yours). So this should just be a temporary solution as you will end up with more and more duplicated lines for each directory you would like to test for. If you consider to change the design, please take the PSR-0 shema into account, it helps to streamline one's codebase and makes it easy to re-use other existing compontents in the PHP world.

---

```
function autoload_class_multiple_directory($class_name) 
{

    # List all the class directories in the array.
    $array_paths = array(
        'classes_1/', 
        'classes_2/'
    );

    foreach($array_paths as $path)
    {
        $file = sprintf('%s%s/class_%s.php', AP_SITE, $path, $class_name);
        if(is_file($file)) 
        {
            include_once $file;
        } 

    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_class_multiple_directory');
```

Comment: Thanks hakre, yes I can see the issue with this solution in long term when I have many directories.

Comment: I came out with another idea - see my edit/ possible solution above :)

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Yeah, I thought about that earlier, too, but wanted to leave some room. Checkout the solution I previously had in mind, I added it now. See the `foreach` and if you assign the filename to a variable (`$file`) you can re-use it better.

Comment: can I ask - what do `%s%s` and `%s` mean?

Comment: that are placeholders for a string-value in sprintf. There are more, you can read more about it in http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php. I normally use sprintf instead of merging variable together inside a string, because it can be more fine-grained controlled and you see all variables after the formatting string as a parameter of it's own.

Answer (score 2):

## Follow PSR-0

The correct way to do this is to adopt the [PSR-0 naming convention](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), and then to use a PSR-0 compatible autoloader, such as the `UniversalClassLoader` from Symfony2's [ClassLoader](https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader) component.

For example:

**a/src/ProjectA/Database/Pdo.php**:

```
<?php

namespace ProjectA\Database;

class Pdo
{
    // your code
}
```

**b/src/ProjectB/Mail/Smtp.php**:

```
<?php

namespace ProjectB\Mail;

class Smtp
{
    // your code
}
```

The symfony ClassLoader is in `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader`.

**autoload.php**:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('ProjectA', __DIR__.'/a/src');
$loader->registerNamespace('ProjectB', __DIR__.'/b/src');
$loader->register();
```

What this does, in essence, is use `spl_register_autoload` to register an autoloader which tries to match the requested classes against all registered paths, if one matches, it is required. Otherwise the autoloader will continue searching.

So what your bootstrap code does is include `autoload.php`, after that all other classes will be autoloaded.

Comment: thanks. I came out with another idea - see my edit/ possible solution above:)