# PHP newbie - PHP Classes autoloading and Securing

Tags: php, autoload

I am interested in learning autoloading, but new to PHP.
I am reading the book "PHP in Action" which writes the autoload method like

```
function __autoload($className) {
 include_once __autoloadFilename($className);
}
function __autoloadFilename($className) {
 return str_replace('_','/',$className).".php";
}
```

I want to pack these methods in a class. will it be better to pack them in an abstract class?

Or in normal class and including it in index.php?

How effeciently I can use the autoloading feature?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713072/how-can-i-load-classes-from-multiple-directories-with-autoload (also see my answer there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Securing an autoloader, ensure:

- That the file you try to load is actually a file. `include` is pretty much like `eval`. For example [disallow url inclusion via the php configuration](http://php.net/allow_url_include).
- That the classname is actually a syntactically correct classname. Could be helpful to secure things ;)

You can also white-list namespaces and/or classnames that are appropriate for your *concrete* autoloader.

Create a class as an autoloader, you must not take the static way, you can just assign any callback with [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register), so you can register multiple autoloaders.

Some quickly written autoloader class stub:

```
class MyAutoloader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->register();
    }
    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this,'autoload'));
    }
    public function autoload($classname)
    {
        if ($this->isInvalidClassName($classname)) return;
        $file = $this->getFileForClassName($classname);
        if ($this->isInalidFile($file)) return;
        require $file; // bail out fatally.
    }
    ...
}

$myAutoloader = new MyAutoloader();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you. I use a dedicated class called Loader with a method called `load()`, which I activate with:

```
spl_autoload_register( 'Utility_Loader::load' );
```