# spl_autoload_register - load only one class from the array

Tags: php, oop

I got the following code for my `autloader.php` to load my classes:

```
define('CLASSES_DIR' , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
  spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
    function myAutoLoader($className) {
      $dir = array(
        CLASSES_DIR. '/admin/resources/classes/',
        CLASSES_DIR. '/admin/resources/classes/Users',
      );
      foreach ($dir as $path) {
        $extension = ".class.php";
        $fileName = $path.$className.$extension;
        $fullPath = $fileName;
        if (!file_exists($fileName)) {
          return false;
        }
        include_once $fullPath;
      }
  }
```

It seems to work fine for the first folder (classes/) but for some reason do not load my classes from /Users. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to check all paths in `$dir` before returning `false`. Try `continue` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7713108/1338292 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/7713219/1338292

Comment: Also, consider looking at [PSR-0 autoloading](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can modify your loader:

```
function myAutoLoader($className) {
  $dir = array(
    // currently there's no need to add `CLASSES_DIR` to each element
    '/admin/resources/classes/',
    '/admin/resources/classes/Users',
  );
  foreach ($dir as $path) {
    $extension = ".class.php";
    // Add `CLASSES_DIR` here
    $fileName = CLASSES_DIR . $path.$className.$extension;
    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
      // if required file exists - include it and return from autoloader
      include_once $fileName;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
define('CLASSES_DIR' , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');
    function myAutoLoader($className) {
      $dir = array(
        CLASSES_DIR. '/admin/resources/classes/',
        CLASSES_DIR. '/admin/resources/classes/Users/'
      );
      $extension = ".class.php";
      foreach ($dir as $path) {
        $fileName = $path.$className.$extension;
        $fullPath = $fileName;
        if (!file_exists($fileName)) {
         }else {
           include_once $fullPath;
         }
      }
  }
  ?>
```